# How to get the correct number of files using querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, image, file, queryselector

I'm working with JavaScript (querySelector) to process one or more images from an HTML input. The problem is that the querySelector returns twice as many images chosen to upload, for example, I choose only one image and the querySelector returns two, and so on. I really don't know why this happens. I've run some `console.log()` to see what happens, but haven't found anything useful.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function () {

    const form = document.querySelector('form')

    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault()
        let files = form.querySelector('[type="file"]').files
        const promises = []

        console.log(files)

        for (let file of files) {
            console.log("Here!!!")
            promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                new Compressor(file, {
                    quality: 0.6,
                    success(result) {
                        //TODO
                        console.log("success")
                    },
                    error(err) {
                        console.log(err.message)
                        reject()
                    },
                })
            }))

        }

    })

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="load">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/compressorjs/1.0.7/compressor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window event is being called multiple times, if all you want to do is upload the image through that form, just remove that window event as it's not necessary and will cause a lot of problems due to the [DOM event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

Here is the working code after removing the window event:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let files = form.querySelector('[type="file"]').files;
  const promises = [];

  console.log(files);

  for (let file of files) {
    console.log('Here!!!');
    promises.push(
      new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        new Compressor(file, {
          quality: 0.6,
          success(result) {
            //TODO
            console.log('success');
          },
          error(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            reject();
          },
        });
      })
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="load">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/compressorjs/1.0.7/compressor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```